# rails datepicker saving todays date instead

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

Hi i am having trouble with saving the date using datepicker , it saves todays date instead and not the one i entered. My start_time has date and time.

this is my form

```
 <%= f.label :start_time, 'start date and time' %>

  <%= f.text_field :start_time, "data-provide" => 'datepicker' %>
  <%= f.time_select :start_time, :ampm => true, :minute_step => 30, class: 'form-control' %>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
});
  });
</script>
```

I have tried changing the date formats but it is not helping.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess.
You have two inputs with same name `start_time`. You should remove time_select I think it gets initialised with today's date which overrides the text_field date